# Firestore internal error on initialisation

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, fatal-error

My app keeps force closing in `onCreate` at the point where I initialise my `Firebase.java` class.

This is the constructor for the `Firebase.java` class.

```
    public Firebase(Context context, ProgressChecker progressChecker) {

    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings = new FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
            .setTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled(true)
            .build();
    db.setFirestoreSettings(settings);
    batch = db.batch();


}
```

This is the stack trace that I get from Crashlytics.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: julio.ai.moyela.tito.timetoolay, PID: 4740
java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error in Firestore (0.6.6-dev).
    at ecb.b(SourceFile:324)
    at ece.run(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
 Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at esr.<clinit>(SourceFile:82)
    at evl.b(SourceFile:103)
    at evm.b(SourceFile:46)
    at evm.a(SourceFile:26)
    at ese.a(SourceFile:70)
    at ebh.<init>(SourceFile:88)
    at dwp.a(SourceFile:1217)
    at dwr.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:272)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at ecb$a.run(SourceFile:190)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Package.getImplementationVersion()' on a null object reference
    at etx.b(SourceFile:742)
    at etx.<clinit>(SourceFile:197)
    at esr.<clinit>(SourceFile:82) 
    at evl.b(SourceFile:103) 
    at evm.b(SourceFile:46) 
    at evm.a(SourceFile:26) 
    at ese.a(SourceFile:70) 
    at ebh.<init>(SourceFile:88) 
    at dwp.a(SourceFile:1217) 
    at dwr.run(Unknown Source) 
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428) 
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:272) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
    at ecb$a.run(SourceFile:190) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

I honestly don't know what else to include because this is a Runtime error. It only occurs in my release build, and it stops occurring when I just get rid of the Firestore initialisation.

I am running these firebase libraries as well.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.3'
```

Comment: Please file a bug report.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: I am currently in contact with the Firebase team but I cannot seem to understand what more is required of me. I mentioned to the rep that it occurs whenever I try to call  `FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();` but he/she is asking for a complete Android project with which they can replicate the issue. Obviously, to which I can't because the issue doesn't occur on a new project or the sample firestore project.

Comment: If you can't show the complete project here either, I doubt you'll get much help.

Comment: I found that the error only occurs when I assign the `FirebaseFirestore` batch object  to the `WriteBatch` object in the same constructor. Do you have any insight about this?